# Creating multiple SalesForce Cases in single login

Tags: c#, salesforce

I'm using a SOAP Web Reference in a C# service for this.

If I call (in my SForceManager class) CreateSForceCase() multiple times within the same connection, I receive the same exact CaseNumber until the connection times out and is reconnected (or if i create a new connection for each).

The problem with this, is that I'm needing to insert upto say 5000 cases, and at 3 seconds per case that will take ~4 hours to insert all 5000 cases. Is there a way to let the API know that I want a brand new case each and every time I create one without logging out?

Here's my Manager code:

```
public String CreateSForceCase(Case sfCase, out string errMsg)
    {
        //Verify that we are already authenticated, if not
        //call the login function to do so
        if (!isConnected()) login();
        errMsg = "";

        sObject[] objCases = new sObject[1];
        for (int j = 0; j < objCases.Length; j++)
            objCases[j] = sfCase;

        //create the object(s) by sending the array to the web service
        SaveResult[] sr = _Binding.create(objCases);
        for (int j = 0; j < sr.Length; j++)
        {
            if (sr[j].success)
            {
                //save the account ids in a class array
                if (_cases == null)
                    _cases = new string[] { sr[j].id };
                else
                {
                    string[] tempcases = null;
                    tempcases = new string[_cases.Length + 1];
                    for (int i = 0; i < _cases.Length; i++)
                        tempcases[i] = _cases[i];
                    tempcases[_cases.Length] = sr[j].id;
                    _cases = tempcases;
                }
                return getCaseNumberFromCaseId(_cases[0]);
            }
            else
            {
                //there were errors during the create call, go through the errors
                //array and write them to the screen
                for (int i = 0; i < sr[j].errors.Length; i++)
                {
                    //get the next error
                    Error err = sr[j].errors[i];
                    errMsg = err.message;
                }
            }
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

and the call within for getting the case # is:

```
public String getCaseNumberFromCaseId(string caseId)
    {
        if (!isConnected()) login();
        sObject[] ret = _Binding.retrieve("CaseNumber", "Case", new string[] { caseId });
        if (ret != null)
            return ((Case)ret[0]).CaseNumber;
        else
            return string.Empty;
    }
```

so something like:

```
SForceManager manager = new SForceManager();
string case1 = manager.CreateSForceCase(...);
string case2 = manager.CreateSForceCase(...);
string case3 = manager.CreateSForceCase(...);
```

then case1 == case2 == case3

but if i do:

```
SForceManager manager = new SForceManager();
string case1 = manager.CreateSForceCase(...);
SForceManager manager = new SForceManager();
string case2 = manager.CreateSForceCase(...);
SForceManager manager = new SForceManager();
string case3 = manager.CreateSForceCase(...);
```

then case1 != case2 != case3 like i expect

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a way to perform this.

The idea is to actually take in a list of "Case objects" and send those all at once, then return a string array of case id's.

I'm not sure what would happen if I try opening too many such that the timeout period may pass in the middle of processing (so it could be improved yet):

```
    public String[] CreateSForceCases(Case[] sfCase, out List<string> errMsg)
    {
        String[] toRet = new string[sfCase.Length];
        errMsg = new List<string>();

        //Verify that we are already authenticated, if not
        //call the login function to do so
        if (!isConnected()) login();
        //errMsg = "";

        sObject[] objCases = new sObject[sfCase.Length];
        for (int j = 0; j < objCases.Length; j++)
            objCases[j] = sfCase[j];

        //create the object(s) by sending the array to the web service
        SaveResult[] sr = _Binding.create(objCases);
        for (int j = 0; j < sr.Length; j++)
        {
            if (sr[j].success)
            {
                //save the account ids in a class array
                if (_cases == null)
                    _cases = new string[] { sr[j].id };
                else
                {
                    string[] tempcases = null;
                    tempcases = new string[_cases.Length + 1];
                    for (int i = 0; i < _cases.Length; i++)
                        tempcases[i] = _cases[i];
                    tempcases[_cases.Length] = sr[j].id;
                    _cases = tempcases;
                }
                toRet[j] = getCaseNumberFromCaseId(_cases[j]);
            }
            else
            {
                //there were errors during the create call, go through the errors
                //array and write them to the screen
                for (int i = 0; i < sr[j].errors.Length; i++)
                {
                    //get the next error
                    Error err = sr[j].errors[i];
                    errMsg.Add(err.message);
                }
            }
        }
        return toRet;
        //return null;
    }
```

There was also a problem in the error handling process in the original, however this one fixes that. I figured I would post my solution in case anyone else has come across this issue...I was not able to find any answer to my question anywhere.